# Help requested to review a popular question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question:
[Assassinate a semi-omniscient crime lord](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/68481/assassinate-a-semi-omniscient-crime-lord)

Now has 30+ answers. It would be helpful if members of the community who have the time available can go through **all** the answers and vote/flag accordingly - otherwise only the first few answers tend to get the recognition or deletion that may be deserved.

The question has been viewed ten thousand times, let's make sure the answers are worth that sort of viewing numbers!

Comment: First time I've ever used up my daily limit for votes!